# A proof: Closure of a set of complex numbers is closed

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I'm assuming the proof should apply for complex, and real numbers. I've offered a proof for complex numbers, and I am not so sure about some of the steps (namely $a_n \in \bar S_c)$ I take so a second look/hints would be appreciated! The only other theorem I have is that a closed set implies every sequence in the set converges to a point in the set.

Let $\bar S = S \cup \partial S$ denote the closure of S, with $\partial S$ being the boundary. Also let $\bar S_c$ be the complement of the closure (sorry if that is unconventional).

Suppose $\bar S_c$ is closed. Consider $z \in \partial S$, then $D(z, r) \cap S_c \neq \emptyset$ for any $r > 0$. Take $a_n \in D\left(z, \frac{r}{n}\right) \cap S_c$ for $n = 1, 2, ...$ Then $a_n \in \bar S_c$ because $a_n \notin S, a_n \notin \partial S$. Clearly, $a_n \rightarrow z$ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$. However, $z \in \bar S$ and $a_n \in \bar S_c$ which means there is a convergent sequence in $\bar S_c$ converging to a point outside $\bar S_c \implies \bar S_c$ is open $\implies \bar S$ is closed.

Comment: What is the definition of $\partial S$ and what is the definition of "closed"?  Surely this is a matter of definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove your result directly from the definition of closure.

And not that $\bar{S}$ contains all the limit points of $S$

Let $x \notin \bar{S}$

Then exists $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \cap S=\emptyset$ and $B(x,r)$ does not contain any limit point of $S$ because if it had a limit point $y$ of $S$ then  from the definition of the limit point $B(x,r)$ as a neighborhood of $y$ would intersect $S$ which is absurd.

Thus $B(x,r) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ \ $\bar{S}$.

So for every element $x$ in the complement of the closure of $S$ we find an open ball with center $x$ which is a subset of the complement.

So  $\mathbb{C}$ \ $\bar{S}$ is open.

Also $a_n$  need not to belong to  $\bar{S}^c$

Take for instance the interval $[0,1]$.

We know that $1 \in \partial{([0,1])}$

Take $$a_n=\begin{cases}\
          1-\frac{1}{n} & n=2k+1\\
          1+\frac{1}{n} & n=2k\\
          \end{cases}$$

and $a_n \to 1$

Comment: Yes haha that seems much more straightforward way to see it. Thank you!

Comment: How do we know such an $r$ exists?

Comment: To construct a sequence you apply the definition inductively for $r=1,\frac{1}{2}...\frac{1}{n}....$

Comment: I’m not sure I follow? The sequence I constructed was for a point in the boundary of S but here you are talking about a point in the complement of the closure?

Comment: @danny i don't understand..you talk about $a_n$?

Comment: I am saying I'm not following how we know that such an $r$ exists to satisfy $B(x, r) \cap S = \emptyset$?

Comment: @danny...From the definition of the closure..remember $x \in \bar{A}$ if for all $r>0$ we have that $B(x,r) \cap A \neq 0$..Now if a point does not belong to the closure of $A$ ,what is the ''negation'' of this definition?

Comment: In other words  every open ball with $x$ as its center  intersects $A$..Now if $x$ is not in the closure then exists a such a ball that does not intersect $A$

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it now

Answer (score 0):

We will prove that $$\bar S =\bigcap_{\ \ \ S\subseteq F\\ F\ \text{closed}} F.$$

Not only will this give us that $\bar S$ is closed as intersection of closed sets, it will give us extremely useful characterization of closure (which I personally prefer to be definition): the closure of $S$ is the smallest closed set containing $S$.

Let $F$ be closed such that $S\subseteq F$. We want to prove that $\bar S = S\cup \partial S\subseteq F$ and by the choice of $F$, it is enough to prove that $\partial S\subseteq F$.

Assume the contrary, i.e. there exists $x\in\partial S$ such that $x\not\in F.$ Then, $x\in F^c$, which is open. Thus, there exists open ball $B(x,r)$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq F^c$. But, since $x\in\partial S$, it means that $B(x,r)\cap S\neq\emptyset$. Let $y\in B(x,r)\cap S$. In particular, $y\in S\subseteq F$, so $B(x,r)\cap F\neq\emptyset$. But this is in contradiction with $B(x,r)\subseteq F^c$. Thus, $\partial S\subseteq F$ and consequently $\bar S\subseteq F$.

Since $F$ was arbitrary, it follows that 
$$\bar S \subseteq\bigcap_{\ \ \ S\subseteq F\\ F\ \text{closed}} F.$$

Let us now prove the other inclusion. Let $$x\in\bigcap_{\ \ \ S\subseteq F\\ F\ \text{closed}} F$$ and assume that $x\not\in S$. We will prove that $x\in\partial S$ then, which will complete our proof.

If $x\not\in\partial S$, then there exists open ball $B(x,r)$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq S^c$. Let $F = B(x,r)^c$. Then, $F$ is closed and $S\subseteq F$, so by our choice of $x$, $x\in F$. Contradiction. Thus, if $x\not\in S$, then $x\in\partial S$, which proves $x\in S\cup\partial S$.

Answer (score 0):

A set is closed if and only if it contains its limit points.

$\partial S = \{\text{limit points  of } S\} \cap \{\text{limit points of } S^c \}$.

It suffices to prove:

**Lemma:**  If $y$ is a limit point of $\overline S = S\cup \partial S$ then $y$ is a limit point of $S$.

Thus every limit point $\overline S$ is in $\{\text{limit points  of } S\} \subset \overline S$.  So $\overline S$ is closed.

Proof of Lemma:

Suppose not.  Let $y$ be a limit point of $\overline S$ that is not a liit point of $S$.  Then there exist an $\epsilon > 0$ so that $B_{\epsilon}(y)$ contains no points (other than possible $y$ itself) that are in $S$.

But $y$ is a limit point of $\overline S$ so $B_{\epsilon}(y)$ contains a $w \in \overline S$.  But $w \not \in S$ so $w \in \overline S \setminus S = \partial S \subset \{\text{limit points of } S\}$.

So $w$ is a limit point of $S$.  Let $\delta = \min(d(w,y), \epsilon - d(w,y))$.

The there exists a point $z\in S$ that is in $B_{\delta}(w)$.

But $d(z,y) \le d(w,z) + d(w,y) < \delta + d(w,y) \le \epsilon - d(w,y) + d(w,y) = \epsilon$.  So $z \in B_{\epsilon} (y)$.

Which is a contradiction.

====

One graphical way of viewing limit  points is $z$ is a limit point of $X$ if $\inf \{d(x,z)|z \in X\} = 0$.

Which would mean if $x$ is a limit point of $\overline S$ means $\inf d(x,y):y\in \overline S = 0$ but $\inf d(y, s):s \in S = 0$ .  So $\inf d(x,s)= 0$.  So $x$ is a limit point of $S$.