# Revised proof: Closure of the set is closed

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I previously attempted to prove this through a contradiction but my proof had some gaps in it and I found another way to think about it thanks to some helpful comments. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426650/a-proof-closure-of-a-set-of-complex-numbers-is-closed). I was wondering my new proof was correct, hopefully I got it down this time. Thank you!

Let $\bar S$ denote the closure of $S$ and let $\bar S_c$ denote is complement (sorry if this is weird notation) and let $\partial S$ be its boundary.

Consider $x \notin \bar S$. Then by definition, $\exists r >0$ so that $B(x, r) \ \cap S = \emptyset$. Therefore $B(x,r) \subseteq S_c$.

I claim that $B(x, r) \cap \partial S = \emptyset$. Suppose not, then $\exists y \in \partial S, y \in B(x, r)$. Therefore, $\exists \epsilon >0 $ so that $\emptyset  \neq S \cap B(y, \epsilon) \subset B(x, r)$. However, this contradicts $B(x, r) \cap S = \emptyset$. Thus, we have $B(x,r) \cap S, B(x, r) \cap \partial S = \emptyset$, so $B(x, r) \subseteq \bar S_c \implies \bar S_c$ is open $\implies \bar S$ is closed.

Comment: For the sake of completeness you can mention that $\epsilon \leq r$ and also i think (i'm not sure) that you have a typo at the part  $\emptyset  = S \cap B(y, \epsilon)$ .....i believe you mean $\neq$

Comment: So yes your proof seems correct...we know that $\bar{S}=S^o \cup \partial{S}$ so you proved that the ball does not intersect the boundary and of course does not intersect the interior because $S^o \subseteq S$

Comment: I really wish more people taught the closure as the intersection of all closed sets above.   Makes this stuff much more straightforward, and you can still get all the other facts from this definition.

Comment: @Randall indeed...in some books is the definition but in some others it is proved..This definition you mention would be useful in this problem of danny because we know that any intersection of closed in a topological space is closed.